# How to use beef-xss on ports other than default 3000?

Tags: linux, kali-linux, ports, beef

I want to use [BeEF-XSS Framework](http://beefproject.com/) over WAN (for educational purposes). The only problem is that my ISP is blocking port 3000. So, after some research, I found [this page](https://nullsec.us/kali-running-beef-xss-on-port-80/) that says:

> However, beef-xss runs as a user by that name in Kali, and standard users cannot use privileged ports (below 1024). There's several methods of fixing this, including a redirect with iptables. However, the best method seems to be using authbind.

I'm a Linux newbie, so can't get enough on those commands and configuration.

- So, I want to know if there is any workaround to change default port for BeEF from 3000 to something that my ISP doesn't block.
  If yes, then how to do it?
- Also, do I need to learn how to use `authbind`?

Answer (score 0):

BeefXSS stores its configuration in a file called `config.yaml`. You can change the port in there

```
http:
    debug: false
    host: "0.0.0.0"
    port: "3000" # Local port webserver is running on

    # If BeEF is running behind a reverse proxy or NAT
    #  set the public hostname and port here
    public: "8.7.6.5"
    public_port: "3000"

    dns: "localhost" 
    web_ui_basepath: "/ui"
    hook_file: "/hook.js" 
    hook_session_name: "BEEFHOOK"
    session_cookie_name: "BEEFSESSION"
```

Source: https://github.com/beefproject/beef/wiki/Configuration#web-server-configuration

Comment: Do I need to use authbind to change the port below 1024 ?

Comment: @VedanshAgrawal You would do well to google these kinds of questions. By merely googling "beefxss authbind" i found the answer to your question in the first search result.

Comment: @VedanshAgrawal if this answer helped you, you should accept it.

Comment: When I search on google, the first site that appears is which I mentioned above and the second is my own question.

Comment: No offense but your answer didn't help me.

Comment: Why not? Your question doesn't say "how do I change the port to something below 1024" it asks how to change it to another port your ISP doesn't block. If your ISP blocks everything above 1024 (sounds like bullshit) then you should mention that. Also, the nullsec site commands are so simple you should be able to copy and paste them if you really want it on port 80 (which is really what you're asking from the sounds of it).